# Returning a calculated value from children processes

Tags: c

I'm writing a program using children processes in C. Basically, the children reads distinct files and calculates a summation. Then they need to return it to main process. How can I return from them to main process?

Comment: [Trying to implement piping in C - shell is hanging and not running commands](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54602168/3422102)? Secret - search `"[c] execvp pipe fork corpse"` in the search box above -- take your pick (it elicits helpful answers from a very knowledgeable source, the `"corpse"` being unique to one JLF).

Comment: `exit(result)` in child.   `waitpid(pid,&status,0) ` trick would work. but only for int value.  `status` will hold result

Comment: Note that you can only return values in the range 0..255 via the exit status.  That is usually inadequate.

Comment: You can use shared memory `(shm_open(), shm_unlink(), mmap(), etc.).` .